# Azure runbook output to email

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, runbook

I am trying to send the output of a VM status from Azure automation runbook into email, I use the below code:

```
function Send-EMail {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$EmailTo,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Subject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Body,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$EmailFrom="noreply@idlebytes.com",  #This gives a default value to the $EmailFrom command
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $SmtpServer = (Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'SmtpHost'),
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $SmtpUsername = (Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'SmtpUsername'),
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $SmtpPassword = (Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'SmtpPassword')
)

    $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($SmtpUsername, $SmtpPassword); 
    $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
    Remove-Variable -Name SMTPClient
    Remove-Variable -Name SmtpPassword

} #End Function Send-EMail

$AutomationCredentialAssetName = "PScredential"

# Get the credential asset with access to my Azure subscription
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $AutomationCredentialAssetName

# Authenticate to Azure Service Management and Azure Resource Manager

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred | Out-Null

$VMStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -Name "vm0" -ResourceGroupName "TestRG" -Status


Send-EMail -EmailTo "admin@idlebytes.com" -Body "$VMStatus" -Subject "vm0 Status"
```

I expect the email output to print the exact status of the output, whereas, it prints the object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachineInstanceView'

Can someone help, how to get the object content as string in email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the variable reference (e.g. $MyVar) into the email body which by default will just return the object type where the output in PowerShell is a special pipeline activity that renders the content either as a listing or as a table.  In order to include content in an email we would have to reference the different properties individually.

Below is an example:

```
[string]$EmailBody = (“Property 1 = [{0}], Property 2 = [{1}], Property 3 = [{2}]” -f $MyObject.Property1, $MyObject.Property2, $MyObject.Property3)
```

The above line would set the variable $EmailBody which is a string to include three properties of an object variable called $MyObject.  If we were to just reference $MyObject for PowerShell output, all the properties would display, but to include the properties in an email, we have to reference them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$VMStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -Name "vm0" -ResourceGroupName "TestRG" -Status
```

To

```
$VMStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -Name "vm0" -ResourceGroupName "TestRG" -Status | select -expand Statuses
```

The first command returns a PSVirtualMachineInstanceView object while the second command returns a string array.

Comment: Hmm. Still no luck. Don't know what I missed. I used the mentioned format.    $Body = Get-AzureRmVM -Name "vm0" -ResourceGroupName "TestRG" -Status | select -expand Statuses