# Azure Runbook Commands

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-runbook

So I have a runbook which automates the shutdown and start-up of my Azure VM during the weekends. This then sends a transactional email confirming that the VPS is shut down/started up.

I have set up my parameters as illustrated. Is there a reason as to why it correctly states the name of my virtual machine (highlighted) in the subject line but in the body of the email (highlighted), it comes up with a completely different name.

Logic would dictate that `$VM.NAME` would be the name of the VPS and not some random command line, so why is this? It's displayed correctly in the subject line but not the email body.

```
   param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [String] $VMName ="ITAMTRADINGVPS",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [String] $ResourceGroupName
)

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}


# If there is a specific resource group, then get all VMs in the resource group,
# otherwise get all VMs in the subscription.
if ($ResourceGroupName -And $VMName) 
{ 
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName
}
elseif ($ResourceGroupName)
{
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

}
else 
{ 
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
}

$vms
# Start each of the VMs
# Stop each of the VMs
foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    $StopRtn = $VM | Stop-AzureRmVM -Force -ErrorAction Continue
    $StopRtn
    Write-Output " this is $StopRtn "

    if ($StopRtn.IsSuccessStatusCode -eq 'True')
    {
        # The VM stopped, so send notice
        Write-Output ($VM.Name + " has been stopped")
        $Username ="xxx"

        $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force

        $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password

        $SMTPServer = "xxx"

        $EmailFrom = "xxxx

        [string[]]$EmailTo = "xxx"
        $Subject = $VM.NAME + " notification of scheduled deallocation"

        $Body = "We'd like to let you know that your Virtual Machine $VM.NAME has successfully deallocated.
        <br>This could either be due to maintenance or a scheduled shutdown. If you were expecting this notification, please disregard this email.
        <br><br>If you need any further assistance, please contact the system administrator on xxx<br><br>Yours Sincerely<br><br>The Technical Design Team<br>xxx<br><br>"

        Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $credential -Usessl -Port 587 -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml
        Write-Output "Email sent succesfully."

    }
    else
    {
        # The VM failed to stop, so send notice
        Write-Output ($VM.Name + " failed to stop")
    }
}
```

**Illustration**

[image]

Comment: what name does it come with the email body? Put some lights on the names

Comment: It’s highlighted in the illustration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable reference (e.g. $VM.Name) into the email body which by default will just return the object type where **the output in PowerShell is a special pipeline activity** which will render the content either as a listing or as a table. In order to include content in an email, **we would have to reference the properties**

```
[string]$EmailBody = (“VMNAME IS = [{0}]” -f $VM.Name)
```

which is similar to `string.format` in `C#`

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049472/7073340)

Comment: OK, so where would I put this command in relation to my own code? Thanks

Comment: @ToddGilbey Just change your content of the `$Body` as per my answer